# Template Linking and Separation of .h and .cc Files

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I've been doing some reading into designing template code have a question about it.  Most of the solutions to problems relating to designing code as templates seem to either be:

1. Put definitions of prototypes into the header file
2. Use the export keyword [like this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.14) (which requires an extra compiler option)
3. Specifically lay out how the templates will be used in the .cc/.cpp file.

For example:

```
// File: foo_impl.cc
// We're working with Class Foo
#include "foo.cc"

template class Foo <int>;
template class Foo <string>;
// etc.
```

None of these methods seem very effective.  Unless if I'm missing something, they don't seem to offer the ability for a user to simply import the header file and link the template code (in a .cc file) without doing extra work.  I was wondering if people could take a look at what I'm doing with my own code and tell me if these violate some kind of best practices protocol or if they could cause an issue that I'm just not seeing.  Here's what I've been doing...

In main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

using namespace std;

int main (void) {
   Foo <string> f ("hello world");
   string s = f.get ();
   cout << s << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

In foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

template <class T>
class Foo {
   public:
      Foo (T);
      T get ();

   private:
      T data;
};

#endif

#include "foo.cc"
```

In foo.cc:

```
#ifndef FOO_CC
#define FOO_CC

#include "foo.h"

template <class T>
Foo :: Foo (T stuff) {
   data = stuff;
}

template <class T>
T Foo <T> :: get () {
   return data;
}

#endif
```

I've been able to compile the code with all warnings in gcc 4.1.2.  Thank you!

Comment: Are you just trying to have separate files like we have for normal c++ files, to have definitions and declaration in separate files? Or you think you can get away with not sharing your implementation code to other user who gonna use your code as a library? Can u elaborate what you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to treat my template code as if it were just another .h and .cc file.  I would like to have a header file that's easy to read through the calls without bulking it up.

Comment: I actually do this too, with a `#ifdef _DEBUG    template class Foo <int>;     #endif` at the end, so I can force it to compile with MSVC and be sure that everything instantiates without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer to put the declaration (.h) in a separate file from the definition (your .cc file). Also, I'd avoid including the .cc file in the .h file. Methods in a .h file should only be inline methods.

Let's say in your example you also had a header file (bar.h) that simply declares a class that has a Foo data member.

Every time you would modify the definition of the Foo class, you would cause a recompile of anyone who includes bar.h, even tough they couldn't care less about the definition of Foo. However, bar.cpp is probably where you actually implement stuff and that file DOES need to include the implementation of your template. This seem trivial in small projects, but becomes a source of headaches in big projects that constantly recompile files for no reason. I've seen people throwing SSDs and Incredibuild at stuff that could be fixed by simple forward declares and better header management.

Personally, I use .imp.h for the implementation of my templates. Including cc files or cpp files seems yucky to me.

For example ( sorry for compilation errors. ;) )

```
// foo.h
#ifndef foo_h
#define foo_h
template< typename T >
struct Foo
{
   Foo( T value );
   void print();
   T _value;     
};
#endif

//foo.imp.h
#ifndef foo_imp_h
#define foo_imp_h
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>
template< typename T >
Foo< T >::Foo( T value ) : _value( value ) {}
void Foo< T >::print() { std::cout << _value << std::endl; }
#endif

// bar.h
#ifndef bar_h
#define bar_h
#include "foo.h"
struct Bar {
   Foo< int > _intFoo;
   Foo< double > _doubleFoo;
   void print();
};
#endif

// bar.cpp
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.imp.h"
void Bar::print()
{
   _intFoo.print();
   _doubleFoo.print();
}

// foobar.cpp
#include "bar.h"
void foobar()
{
   Bar bar;
   bar.print();
}
```

Had the defintion of foo be included in or by foo.h, bar.cpp and foobar.cpp would have been recompiled. Since only bar.cpp is concerned with Foo's implementation, splitting the defintion and declaration of Foo in two files and not having foo.h include foo.imp.h at the end saved me a recompile of foobar.cpp.

This is something that happens all the time in projects and can be very easily avoided by following the .h/.imp.h rule I explained above. The reason you never see this in stuff like STL or boost is because you are not modifying those files. It doesn't matter if they are in one or two files. But in your own projects, you will be constantly modifying the definitions of your templates and this is how you reduce recompilation times.

If you already know beforehand which types are actually going to be used with your template, than do not even bother with the .imp.h file. Put everything in a .cpp and do this at the end

```
// foo.cpp
// Implementation goes here.
// You might need to put something in front so that it gets exported from your DLL,
// depening on the platform
template class foo< int >;
template class foo< double >;
```

Comment: Based on an answer from @Seth Carnegie, I've decided to rename my .cc file to a .impl.h extension so that it doesn't get compiled.  Then I got rid of the include statement from the .impl.h so that there's only one include.

Also, whenever I work with non-template class files, I always only include the header into the implementation and not the other way around to avoid this issue.

Comment: ooh, I gotcha.  `foobar.cpp` requires `Bar` to be fully defined, which requires `Foo` to be fully defined, but the `foobar.cpp` TU does _not_ include `Foo`s implementation, because it doesn't call any of those functions.  My comments in Seth Carnegie's answer were because I couldn't think of an example like this.  Good!

Comment: Ditto.  I think this is the way I'll go as I develop code and once I feel it's ready to be in it's "completed" stage, I'll switch it over so that only the .h include is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with basic ideology of .h and .cc files. When building libraries, the idea is to share only your header files and not your implementation (mean .cc files). This is also the basics OOP's encapsulation, abstraction etc, to hide the implementation details.

Now templates in C++ violates this principle, bcoz C++ is a compiled language. And compiler generates all the needed code during compilation. Now to adhere to OOP we end up with fragile templates which not 100% generic in nature.

**Keep declaration and definitions separate (SHARING implementation)**

If you are just want to keep things clean and in order, then you can include your implementation file in another header. I think it should be header file as this goes with basic convention that we share .h files and we keep .cc files not to be shared (until you are sharing the code itself). Here is how the files look.

**foo.h**

This is simple file with including `foo_impl.h`.

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
template <class T>
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo (T);
    T get();
  private:
    T data;
};

#include "foo_impl.h"
#endif
```

**foo_impl.h**

This one is bit different from the norms. Here we are not guarding the header file content. Instead we will raise an error if some one included `foo_impl.h` directly (which in our case does not make sense).

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#error 'foo_impl.h' is not supposed to be included directly. Include 'foo.h' instead.
#endif

template <class T>
Foo <T> :: Foo (T stuff) {
   data = stuff;
}

template <class T>
T Foo <T> :: get () {
   return data;
}
```

Now if some one tries to include `foo_impl.h` directly will get error like:

```
foo_impl.h:2:2: error: #error 'foo_impl.h' is not supposed to be included directly. Include 'foo.h' instead.
```

PROS:

- Separation of concerns, implementation and declarations are in separate files.
- Safe guarding implementation file avoid accidental inclusion.
- The header file used to include is not bloated with implementation code.

CONS:

- As mentioned above, have to share the implementation.

NOTE: For not sharing code for templates, I think you already know that you have to declare all possible types in the which the end user can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Including .cc files is bad news and defeats the purpose of separating implementation from declaration.

Define templates in headers:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

template <class T>
class Foo {
   public:
      Foo (T);
      T get ();

   private:
      T data;
};

// implementation:


template <class T>
Foo :: Foo (T stuff) {
   data = stuff;
}

template <class T>
T Foo <T> :: get () {
   return data;
}

#endif
```

If you really prefer 2 files then make the second one a .h too. Name it foo_impl.h or something.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to affect the seperation of interface and implementation for templates by `#include`ing the implementation of the templates at the end of the header, but there are three problems with how you are doing it:

1. You're including the .h file in the .cc file. Don't; there should be nothing but function definitions in the implementation file.
2. You're .cc file should not be named .cc, it should be named .template or something similar to let people know that it should not be compiled (like headers should not be compiled)
3. The `#include "foo.cc"` in foo.h should be *inside* the include guards, not outside.

Done this way, there is no extra work for the user to be done. All you do is `#include` the header, and you're done. You don't compile the implementation.

Comment: Thank you!  This is definitely a step up from where I started.  On the note of including files, should I always be including the .cc file into the .h rather than the other way around?

If so, what's the rational for this?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you do not include your templt inside your .h file. have the .tmplt include the .h file instead. Other .h files normally will only need your declaration (unless there's some inline code in the .h file that needs you definition). .cpps are the ones who will need the defintion and they will include the .templt, which includes the .h file automatically for you

Comment: @dorsalfinsalsa to reply to fronsacqcs comment and your question at the same time, you can just as easily have the other .h files include the .tmplt file. It doesn't really matter anyway, because one way or another the contents of the .tmplt (and the .h) will end up in each .cc file exactly once. You can choose, though I've never seen the .tmplt include the .h and the user include the .tmplt before, I think that might be weird and unintuitive.

Comment: Also make sure you don't compile the .impl.h as a source file. It should only end up compiled by virtue of being included by other files, not by being on the command line or in the project or anything (treat it exactly like a .h file)

Comment: @fronsacqc - By what you're saying, am I correct in understanding that if I create my own non-template class that I'll need to include the template header in my class header file and then I'll need to include the template implementation (which itself includes the template header) into the class implementation file?

Comment: @dorsalfinsalsa yes exactly, if you do it the way he suggests. I recommend having the .h include the .tmplt and everything else only include the .h everywhere.

Comment: @SethCarnegie That seems counter-intuitive to make someone else that might be using my template code to do extra work just to use it.  I prefer to just include the template header and then just use it.  And on a completely different note, thanks for helping me out on my very first post on this site!  I really appreciate the discussion!

Comment: @SethCarnegie : I agree it's more work, but your build system will scale a lot better.

Comment: @fronsacqc: I don't see how.  Every single TU still includes both files, how does it scale better?  Also, I think that way interferes with template specialization, if any are specialized in the implementation.

Comment: @dorsalfinsalsa : Exactly. This way, clients of your non templated class will never be affected by a change in the definition of your class. This can save you lots of recompiles. It requires a bit more discipline, but it's worth the trouble if you ask me.

Comment: @MooingDuck : Take a look at my sample code in my reply. I think you'll understand.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are including `foo.cc` in `foo.h`, you'll make your life simpler by putting *all* the code into `foo.h` and getting rid of `foo.cc`. There is no advantage to be gained from splitting the code into two pieces.

Answer (score 0):

export keyword is deprecated in c++11. So, you will end up with deprecated code. You put your defintions in the header file itself.

Comment: It is not deprecated.  It is gone.  [Well, the keyword is still reserved, but it no longer has any meaning.  The export features is entirely removed.]